# Authenticate using Email or Phone Number

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having a page which is a Login Page. I want to authenticate the User using the email address or the phone number in the `Username` section.

I am using the following method :

```
public Customer Authenticate(string uname, string pass)
        {
            string query = "select * from tblCustomer where (Username=@email OR Username=@phone) and Password=@pass ";

            List<SqlParameter> lstP = new List<SqlParameter>();

            lstP.Add(new SqlParameter("@uname", uname));
            lstP.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", pass));

            DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query, lstP);

            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return new Customer();
            }
            else
            {
                return SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["CustomerID"]));
            }
        }
```

Now in this method how do i add the 3rd parameter ?? i.e. the `phone number` ?

Any ideas how should i go about it ? **P.S.: I am using a 3-tier architecture**

Following is the code for `SelectData` incase needed :

```
public static DataTable SelectData(string query, List<SqlParameter> lstParams)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddRange(lstParams.ToArray());

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: i could do that , but then i would have to add another parameter to the `method's` parameter  :  `Authenticate(string uname, string pass)` and i am entering **only one** `Username` .. Then how should i pass the 3 parameters?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: If the input contains one value (`uname`), and the database has one column associated with that value (`Username`), then why do you need to add another one in the first place?  Why do you need to compare the same column with the same input value twice?

Comment: i  have a column named `Username` which i want to authenticate against the `Email` or `Phone` fields of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* a third parameter.  You have only these:

```
string uname, string pass
```

If that `uname` value can be either an email address or a phone number, and in your table you have a `Username` column, then you'd match against that column:

```
select * from tblCustomer where Username=@uname and Password=@pass
```

It doesn't matter what intuitive contents that field contains, whether it's an email or a phone number.  The field is a string.  Any unique string can be a username.

---

On the other hand, if the database table has *two* separate fields (`Email` and `Phone`, for example), then you can simply add two parameters to the query:

```
select * from tblCustomer where (Email=@email OR Phone=@phone) and Password=@pass
```

And add the same value as the parameters:

```
lstP.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", uname));
lstP.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", uname));
```

---

*On the other hand*, if users are *entering* the value into separate fields and you have separate values coming in to the method:

```
string email, string phone, string pass
```

Then you can use those in the query:

```
    select * from tblCustomer where (Email=@email OR Phone=@phone) and Password=@pass
```

And add the separate values as the parameters:

```
lstP.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));
lstP.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", phone));
```

---

The point is, all you need to do is pass the values into the query.  The structure of how you handle the values doesn't change whether they're an email address or a phone number.  Both are strings and are semantically indistinguishable to the code.

---

**Note:** Please make sure you're properly hashing user passwords.  This code *suggests* (but doesn't necessarily guarantee) that you may be storing user passwords in plain text.  Doing so would be *grossly irresponsible* to your users.  Please hash passwords so their original text can't be retrieved.

Comment: Thank You @David. The second case was the one which i needed. Explained beautifully !